# Transferring an app to another Firebase account

Tags: firebase

I have a few apps under my personal firebase account for testing, but now need to transfer an app to a client's account for billing purposes. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 418, accepted):

I recently shifted ownership of one of my projects to another account. All you have to do is:

1. Go to your Firebase console, and select the project you want to shift.
2. Select the cog icon besides the project name on top right.
3. Select Permissions from the flyout.
4. Select Advanced permission settings hyperlink.
5. You've reached the IAM & Admin page of Firebase.
6. Click on `+Add` button on top.
7. Enter the email ID of the account that you want to transfer the project to.
8. In the dropdown, Select a role > Project > Owner. Click add
9. You will receive a confirmation email. Click the link in the email to accept the invitation.
10. Accept the invitation, and go to IAM & Admin page of the transferred project.
11. Use remove button to delete the previous user

Comment: after 7th step it says `Error: The update cannot be completed. Group accounts are not permitted as owners on projects.`

Comment: @LukasLiesis can you check with a single user email id. I guess you're using a groups account. The error is self explanatory though.

Comment: I was not sure about what group account is because was not using Google accounts for business myself. It turned out I've added the user who is part of a group on google for the business account. The error was definitely not self-explanatory. There is no mentioning what kind of group error talks about and there was no mention at all about Google for business anywhere on the page.

Comment: does this still work can you update the instructions

Comment: worked like a charm :) 

I wanted to add a new owner in order to switch google play account linked with Firebase project.

Comment: Will this also migrate the database and all other features from the previous owner to new owner?

Comment: @PrasadW yes it will

Comment: What about Billing? Is new owner in charge of payments?

Comment: @chetan92 What happens if the previous owner (who was deleted) deletes the project from his console?

Comment: do you need to update to client's api key?

Comment: @kchetan can we merge firebase iOS & Android apps from different projects into one firebase project as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365143/merging-firebase-ios-android-apps-from-different-projects-into-one-firebase-pr

Answer (score 32):

@SergeyKopanev

## Transfer the billing

After deleting the first user in the **Firebase Console**, login to your **Google Cloud Platform** console with your new user. 
Go to **Billing > Account Management**

[image: Change billing screenshot]

Click on the three dots next to the project ID you just transferred, and select **Change billing**. 
Confirm by clicking on **Set account** and you are done !

Answer (score 21):

*Note that this is an old answer and there might be more up to date solutions below.*

---

This is a reply received after emailing to **`firebase-support@google.com`**, which is the *official firebase support email* after gogle acquired firebase in late 2014.

> From: firebase-support@google.com
>   In order to transfer ownership of a Firebase instance, we need you to
>   do two things: add the new owner as a collaborator; then, fill in the
>   form below and email it to us as written verification. This must be
>   sent from the email address which owns the Firebase instance.

```
----------------- 
REQUEST TO TRANSFER OWNERSHIP
I authorize the Firebase team to make **<new owner’s email>** the owner of https://**<firebase instance>**.firebaseio.com effective immediately. I have added **<new owner’s email>** as a collaborator to verify the email address is correct and to certify that I am the current owner. I understand that I am effectively granting **<new owner’s email>** full read and write access to all stored data for this instance.
-----------------
```

Comment: It looks like this is no longer supported. I added a new answer below for the new support ticket system.

Comment: You don't have to send a special mail anymore.

Answer (score 20):

It is more simple now.

1. Click gear icon beside **Project Overview**
2. Click on **Users and Permissions**
3. Click on **Add Member**
4. Type the email address and choose the role as **Owner**
5. Click on **Add Member**

[image]

[image]

and that's it you are done. An invitation will be sent to the email id. They just need to accept.

Comment: Nice Answer with Image Steps

Comment: Is this the same as the above with IAM & Admin Page?

Answer (score 14):

follow this steps :
- select you project
- from left side menu select

[image: Menu]

(Users and Permissions) from settings icon

- Click on +Add button on top.
- Enter the email ID of the acc to transfer the project to.
- In the dropdown, Select a role > Project > Owner. Click add
- Check mail in the email added above.
- Accept the invite, and go to IAM & Admin page of the transferred project.
- Use remove button to delete the previous user

Answer (score 8):

For projects on the new Firebase Console (at https://console.firebase.google.com), this is now a self-service process. See the answer to this question: [How to add collaborators to a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app/37571602#37571602) for a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 8):

Here from my account just add a different email as owner role

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I sent an email to the support email address and a bot replied:

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------
>
> From: <support@firebase.com>
>
> To: <REDACTED>
>
> Transfer Ownership of Firebase Account
>
> Hey there,
>
> In order to more efficiently process your issue, we now only accept
>   new support requests through our support portal at
>   https://firebase.google.com/support/.
>
> Please submit your inquiry there. Thanks in advance!
>
> Cheers, Firebase Support

To make my transfer request I created a ticket under Account Services https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/

Answer (score 0):

If `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()` is giving you the reference from the old database already deleted try this:

Change the name of your "package_name": "**com.old.appname**" on all occurrences to be different from the old one.

[image: Find in folder]

- Right-click on your project folder
- click on *Find in folder* option
- search `com.old.appname` and change all occurrences to `com.new.appname`