# How to add collaborators to a Firebase app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

On the latest version of `Firebase` (Announced during Google I/O 2016), how do I add other people to my project or app whom I want to `collaborate` with? I came across IAM roles through `Settings > Permissions`. Is this the right way? If I add person there and assign a role, say Editor, will he/she be notified about it through email? Will a request be sent or will they be added directly to that role?

Comment: I'm having problems adding a collaborator with the answer below. Has anyone seen this problem before? http://i.imgur.com/2CFQZqD.jpg

Answer (score 276, accepted):

To give people access to your Firebase project, take these steps:

1. Select your project in the new [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. In the top left, next to the project name, click the settings/cog wheel icon
   [image: From the firebase console]
3. Click <kbd>Users and Permissions</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Add member</kbd>
5. Enter the email address of the user to add and select the appropriate role as per your requirement
6. Click the second <kbd>Add member</kbd> button

The newly added users will get an email with the subject `[Firebase] Invitation to join project` and an option to `Accept Invite` in the body. Be certain to let them know that you added them so that they can accept the invite.

Comment: If you have Google Cloud Storage buckets in the same project, does this give role give the user access to these buckets as well? If so, any way to restrict access only to Firebase?

Comment: @Frank: Does the user being invited have to be a registered Firebase user?

Comment: I've been through nearly all of the Console and most of the docs and never came across a reference to this IAM system.  Why is this not documented anywhere?

Comment: I have added a new member with roles mentioned in the others section which includes for example "Firebase Rules System", but when I login using the member ID, I am not able to see the project for which I had been given role.

Comment: Google IAM doesn't offer any Firebase-specific permissions. I had to add a developer as an **Editor** for the *entire* project. Is there any plan to offer more fine-grained access control? E.g., will I ever be able to let my dev access only Firebase Analytics and Config?

Comment: We're aware that role-based access to specific Firebase features would be useful to a lot of our developers. But as usual, we don't commend on whether or when this will be implemented.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What next to do after someone has added me to their firebase. How do I access the project? It is not clear anywhere what the permitted member needs to do next.

Comment: @AbhinavRaja you direct your browser to: https://console.firebase.google.com and you should see the project appear in your projects list. Click on it and you are in.

Comment: The answer here from @Franklin Antony is the absolutely most sueful one as it points out in google cloud console the role you need to use is under "Project" and is "Editor" which igves acces to the whole Firebase project **nothing** to do  'firebase rules system"

Comment: There is no Users and Permissions in Settings of my Firebase project

Comment: It's really unfortunate that Editor access to Firebase gives the user Editor access to the entire GCP project. This is unacceptable for most business use cases. Firebase just had a big push for being 'business ready' at Google I/O, but without a separate "Firebase Editor" permission, it's a big problem for many businesses.

Comment: The ability to give people access to specific Firebase features is rolling out at the moment. If you don't have the option to give granular access permission in a few weeks, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is this still the correct way to add collaborators?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We are having different environments for one of our solutions. We've created different firebase databases as part of single project. We would like to add access control to these databases depending on users e.g. prod firebase database will be accessible to only few users where as other environment's firebase database will be accessible to all the users. Would this be possible to achieve with the latest release of firebase?

Comment: Access control is for all databases in a project, you can't control it per database. If that is required, you should put different environments into separate projects. Please open a new question in the future.

Comment: This is a great change however why does access to 'Quality' also need access to 'Analytics'? It seems a bit restricting to have to give access to revenue/sales data to anyone that wants to see just crashlytics logs.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE 6/18/2018** - changes to Cloud Console and Google's functionality, the original solution may no longer work as shared in comments. For a recent project, I was able to add other users and permissions via Firebase console as indicated below.

[image: Manage users in Firebase Console]

---

**Old Solution**

Originally you had to choose `Editor` but you do not have to any more. There are new roles added to Google Cloud IAM in the `other` section, namely the `Firebase Rules System` role.

[image: Firebase Rules Admin Role]

[image: Assign Role To User]

If you add a user to a Google Cloud `project` using IAM and assign them this role, they can access Firebase project by visiting:

- https://console.firebase.google.com

The authorized project(s) should appear and they can access, without access to the rest of the Google Cloud project.

Comment: I was able to add the `Firebase Rules System` role to a user, thanks to your suggestion. However, I couldn't find it in the main list of roles. Any idea why?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I added a Firebase user this way, thinking it was the right way to do so, but in the end, when the added user wanted to see the project, going in the firebase console, the project was not showed. Any other tips ?

Comment: @HondaGuy I'm unsure as the Gcloud admin console has been changing lately. Check the `Other` section in the `Roles` dropdown and mouseover it. Try a couple times perhaps. I still see it in my console.

@JohanChouquet if it doesn't work for you, you can set `Editor` role for the user and they will see it. I know that was advertised as beta so I suspect Google has option to remove or change until GA

Comment: This solution previously worked for me, but have now discovered that the user added can no longer access the Firebase project. They must have changed the permissions on that role. Have had to add the user as Editor role to the whole Google Cloud project now, which gives a lot of access to other parts of the project they don't need :(

Comment: Right, this is no longer a valid answer as this permission only covers the rules system but does not give them access to the general Firebase project.

Comment: Google is famous for changing their features with little regard to breaking changes. I'll add notice at top of answer to warn others just in case.

Answer (score 11):

In latest version of the console adding is in a bit different.

1. Go To `Your Project` -> `Project Overview` -> `Users and Permissions` . This will open up new Pop Up.
2. Now click on the `+Add` to add the Members.
3. Now Add Email Id of the member. Now below that choose from the dropdown `Project` -> `Collaborator` as shown below and `Save`. Thats all! You are done.

---

[image]

Answer (score 9):

If you're adding a Project owner, an invite will be sent to the new user. However, no email invites are sent for the Project Editor/Viewer roles.

Comment: it throws error if i try to add 2nd owner and it throws error too if i try to remove myself as owner 1st.

Answer (score 7):

From `Users and Permissions` tab, now, at I/O 2019, it was announced a new option to give permissions.

You can now assign to a specific collaborator, access to **Analytics**, **Develop**, **Quality** and **Grow**, each one with **Admin** privileges or **View** privileges.

[image]