# How to add another account to Firebase Console (NOT the project)?

Tags: firebase-console

On every work day I'm logged into two Gmail accounts - personal and work.
When I open Firebase Console, I'm already logged in with my personal account. Clicking on user icon **only lets me log out** which screws up my Gmail sessions.

Just like in Gmail, it would be nice if I can add account to FB Console.

This has nothing to do with collaborators for the FB project.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app seems to be the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add collaborators to a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app)

Answer (score 4):

I found official answer for your question .  I was in same situation and resolved issue with this:

[image]

[Official Link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000272?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

1. Start another browser.
2. Login with work account.
3. Create project.
4. Give your other account access rights to the project (if your employer agrees).
5. Use your favourite browser from there on.

Comment: I have put forward the feature request to FB. Here is what they have to say: "We're definitely aware that many users, such as yourself, would like Firebase to support multiple accounts. We're exploring potential solutions, but I can't share any details or timelines at this time. We'll keep your feedback in consideration moving forward though."

Comment: Any news on this?