# Firebase Project Invitation

Tags: firebase, permissions, google-cloud-messaging, sharing

I've a project using Firebase, and I need to add an owner to the project.
This is how I added him:

1. Opened the project in the Firebase console.
2. Clicked on the settings wheel next to the project name, and selected permissions.
3. Firebase launches a new page "IAM & Admin".
4. Pressed on Add, which shows a popup.
5. Entered the user gmail address, which auto completes so it could never be a wrong email.
6. Selected the role as OWNER.
7. Pressed on ADD button.

Now it shows me the user in the permissions list, with the message:

> Invitation sent. Pending acceptance.

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37571602/968194), which says :

> The newly added users may sometimes not be getting an email invite. So be certain to let them know that you added them.

I've let the user share his screen with me on Skype, and this is what happens:
The user do get an email invitation, when he presses on accept invitation, the firebase console page is opened with **the project name in the url** !

But it doesn't show the project which I've shared. it just loads the Firbease console showing different projects that he owns from before !

And I still see this message:

> Invitation sent. Pending acceptance.

Comment: I'll update my answer that you quote, because in recent cases where I've tried this the new user **did** get an email invite.

Comment: Btw: did your collaborator just pots the same problem to the firebase-talk mailing list? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/i8NqdOPY0qI Or is this a different instance?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the update !

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No that's not him

Comment: Hmmm... that means we have two potentially unrelated reports. :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Frank has mentioned this is probably a bug that should be fixed in the firebase console.

I've managed to do a workaround by not using Firebase permissions, but by using [Google Cloud service](https://console.cloud.google.com) instead.

In Google Cloud Services console I do have access to the same projects in Firebase console, so I opened the project, from the menu selected **IAM & ADMIN** which looks exactly the same as the IAM & ADMIN in firebase console, I've added the collaborator as an owner exactly as I've mentioned in the details above, and what do you know ! an email invitation was sent, the user accepted the request successfully.

And when he opened his Firebase console again, the project is now available in his projects list.

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to work around it. The bug should indeed be fixed soon.

Comment: Life saver really!

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you. It's appalling that this is still an issue 5 years after.

Answer (score 7):

*firebaser here*

This is a known issue in the workflow for adding Owners that was introduced recently. It should be fixed soon, but in the meantime you can work around it by first adding the user as an Editor (no invite/accept workflow required), and THEN adding the user as an Owner (accept invitation workflow should be properly displayed).

Comment: I've tried doing this, instead of adding the user as an owner, I've added him as an editor or viewer, so that I would then change his role as an Owner once he gain access, but he never did gain access to the project in his firebase console !

Comment: Omg, this still doesn't work in July 2019. Nothing happens when I tap that owner invitation button. But it works to be added as an Editor. If an invite for being an owner is sent while the user is already an Editor, then i'm being redirected to the console, but the owner access rights are still not granted. Did not expect this from Google.

Comment: Adding a user as an owner works fine for me these days, and has done so for the past few years. Since it's unlikely that the service **sends** an email to some users and not to others, at this point I'd assume that the email is getting caught in (spam) filters for those users that don't receive them,

Answer (score 2):

Tried the GCP approach with same result - nothing! BUT, after an hour the profect appeared in my member's Firebase and GCP dashboards.

Comment: This rather sounds like a comment, not like an answer.