# Google Firebase - User invitation does not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I want to give a colleague access to one of my Firebase projects. I enter the project click on the gear and select IAM link and the add the user by clicking on the "ADD" link. I enter his email address and the role. My colleague receives the invitation-eMail, clicks on it, logs into his account. The problem is: Nothing happened. He can't see the project and on my end I see the invitations as open (not accepted) still. Is there anyone who can please help me with this?

Comment: Same problem here. It looks like the system is broken right now?

Comment: *firebaser here* There is indeed a problem with invites at the moment. See this question and answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949167/firebase-project-invitation