# Same firebase project for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase

My friend have finished setting up a Firebase backend for an Android application, and the project is on his private firebase account. Now I am starting to code the iOS version which should access the same Firebase backend.

My question is this... do I need to get his firebase email and password to work on the project or there​ is a way to import it to my account so I can work on it ?
tip: The solution should be like that, if any change happen in  iOS or Android, must change in both of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add collaborators to a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple developers to a single project, and you can have multiple apps added to your project. Do the following: your friend must add you to the project, and you must create an iOS application for that project in Firebase.

Comment: If he adds me to the project, I can access it from my account?

Comment: Yes. You will be able to do it.