# How to share access to Firebase Analytics data without exposing the rest of Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I know how to add collaborators to a Firebase project, and that I can assign specific roles to each collaborator, which are tied to certain permissions.
However, no role seems to fit my requirements.

I want to share access to Firebase Analytics with non-technical, marketing people. I have to avoid exposing the rest of Firebase to them, especially the Database and Storage buckets.

Since I could not find anything about this in the Firebase Analytics documentation, I'm assuming that this is not (yet) possible using Firebase alone.
I also found a comment by a Firebase engineer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37571602/6660476), which indicates that Firebase does not support this for the time being:

> We're aware that role-based access to specific Firebase features would
>   be useful to a lot of our developers. But as usual, we don't commend
>   on whether or when this will be implemented. – Frank van Puffelen Jun
>   2 at 9:36

Is there any way to share the data from Firebase Analytics? Perhaps on another platform, where the collaborators cannot see anything about the other features of Firebase?

I have the feeling that I'm missing something. Shouldn't it be possible to simply link Firebase Analytics with Google Analytics, in such a way that marketing people, who are used to Google Analytics already, have a familiar experience (similar to website analytics) doing their app analytics tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can connect Google Analytics and Firebase. To get more detailed how to do it, you can visit this website:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en&ref_topic=2587085

It's at least a solution to seperate marketing and development.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own custom dashboard by retrieving your firebase dataset and customize that for your clients. Firebase has access for it dataset. For more information visit following links

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data