# Firebase Console Permission

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-analytics

I would like to know if a Firebase project can share only specific service?

I own one Firebase project and I want to share only the analytics part to my teammate. But I go to console.firebase in `users and permissions -> IAM`, I can only choose my teammate to be an owner, editor, viewer etc. for the complete project.

Is there a way, I can only share the access to the analytics part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share access to Firebase Analytics data without exposing the rest of Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501988/how-to-share-access-to-firebase-analytics-data-without-exposing-the-rest-of-fire)

Comment: Thanks, but to create a property of Firebase app in Google Analytics they need to have owner permission of Firebase right? what if, If I share 'owner' permission to them after linked with GA then I remove them from Firebase console. Will Analytics in GA still available?

Comment: That's correct, I believe if you then remove them as a user, they'll lose access to the Firebase analytics data. Unfortunately, from [Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app/37571602#comment75655623_37571602), there aren't any granular permissions for Firebase access yet. This acts as a workaround somewhat in that it doesn't require the user to go through the Firebase console although they do have access to it (it's [security through obscurity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) which isn't good really).

Comment: What if I work with outsources for analytics part, not my teammate, If I share access to them to use GA for analytics they still can come to my firebase console anytime right? Do you have any suggestion to prevent some kind of privacy like this? Thanks,