# Can I use two Firebase accounts for same app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created an Firebase account, under which I created a Firebase project for my **iOS app project**, I am working on Facebook login.

Now, another developer joint our team, he is working on **the same iOS project**, however, he used his Firebase account created a Firebase project with the same name, he is working on Twitter login.

I am wondering, we are now working on the same iOS project codebase, however, we use two different Firebase accounts for different authentication method (Facebook login, and Twitter login). Will there be problem in future for our app? Or it is fine to use two Firebase accounts for the same iOS project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it can technically work, it does sound odd to have a separate project for each provider.

More commonly you'll have a separate project for each developer for their development work. And then a common project where both developers are collaborators for the integration of all the pieces. To add a collaborator to a project, see [How to add collaborators to a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app).