# How can I add an Android App to an existing Firebase Project that is already in use in an iOS App?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, merge, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using a Firebase project in my iOS App. I now want to start using the same Firebase project for an Android App with all its database and storage.

Comment: All the apps added to a Firebase project (Android, iOS, web) all have access to the same data using the same APIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under your app's **Overview** menu, you should press **Add another app** and select **Android**.

[image: side menu of application]

[image: Add another app section]

[image: menu appearing after clicking Add another app]

Comment: Is it that simple? don't we need to write any script or some kind of API to have the two apps use one database?

Comment: Yes, it should be this easy. If you are uncertain about the outcome, try it with a small test app.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks sir

Comment: @MumtazHussain this is correct or you could use the Android Studio assistant, in order for that to work you have to have access to the Firebase Project before (your Google account has to) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app