# Firebase App Transfer Ownership using the portal

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

The process to request to transfer an app ownership described at [Transferring an app to another Firebase account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688716/transferring-an-app-to-another-firebase-account) is not working anymore, after send and email requesting the change I received the following message:

*Hey there,
In order to more efficiently process your issue, we now only accept new support requests through our support portal at https://firebase.google.com/support/.
Please submit your inquiry there. Thanks in advance!*

Which are the steps to doing it using Firebase Support portal?

Solution: I did a request on the new portal, under [account services](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services) and a representative communicated with me through email to do the owner transfer. Thanks [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is actually a lot simpler nowadays. You can simply add a new collaborator to the project and make them an owner. See [How to add collaborators to a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569460/how-to-add-collaborators-to-a-firebase-app/37571602#37571602)

Comment: Thanks Frank, the only problem is that I'm using the legacy dashboard (I'm not able to upgrade the apps) and these steps seems to be for the new console, aren't they?

Comment: Ownership transfers for legacy projects are no longer possible. If you have a business reason that prevents you from upgrading to the new console (which makes this a self-service operation) and needing to transfer ownership, reach out to customer support as the auto-response suggested.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the thing is that the issue that we are having is not being considered as one of the possible options under components in the "Problem Solving" section

Comment: It probably falls under [account services](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I will try it