# Android project, change Firebase Account

Tags: android, firebase, google-account

I have created an application and implemented Firebase (Auth, Analytics, Remote Config, Crash Reporting) with it.

Now i need to change the Firebase account because in my collaborator account we will implement Realtime Database with BLAZE plan. (we need more than 100 concurrent connections to db)

1. Is it possible to use some features from my account and some from other?
2. Is it possible to transfer current project from my account to his
   account?
3. If both answers are NO :P, to create a new project on collaborator's account and connect it with application, will it be enough changing JSON generated from Firebase Console or this wont work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1- Yes, it's possible and you can follow [this tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) to do so.

2- If you want to simply switch projects, generate a new JSON on the console and remove the old one. If you want to migrate your database, it's possible, just check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688716/transferring-an-app-to-another-firebase-account).

3- Both answers are "yes" so, try them out.

Answer (score 13):

Follow the below steps, to switch firebase account

1. Go to your firebase console, and select the project you want to shift
2. Select the icon besides the project name on top right.
3. Select Permissions from the flyout.
4. You've reached the IAM & Admin page of firebase.
5. Click on +Add button on top.
6. Enter the email ID of the account to transfer the project to.
7. In the dropdown, Select a role > Project > Owner. Click add
   Check mail in the email added above.
8. Accept the invite, and go to IAM & Admin page of the transferred project.
9. Use remove button to delete the previous user

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very resourceful, Thank you!

Comment: Dear @VivekHande. Please, give credit to the owner of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39525119/8719007.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simple trick to logout from old Firebase account and login to new Firebase account in Android Studio, click on highlighted icon, Sign out from old account and relogin with new account of Firebase:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I go to my project Gmail firebase console and

1. Go to project setting
2. go to (Users and permissions)
3. Invite new user and accept the invitation

My firebase account change to my project