# How to change Firebase google-services from a gmail to another gmail

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-play-services

As practice, I have made an app and used my own Gmail to access the firebase database but for some personal reason I want to change the current Gmail. I tried to do that by downloading the new google-services.json file into the app and replace it with the old one but I get an error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.****'

I was wondering if it is possible to do that or should I just make a new project and copy everything.

Comment: The mail address of the account has no inflluence on the google-services.json. If you want to use a different account, just invite that email address to *the same project*. You don't need to re-download the google-services.json for that.

Comment: How can i invite that email address to the same project ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688716/transferring-an-app-to-another-firebase-account/39525119#39525119

Comment: oh i did it thank you very much