# Firebase Analytics - Merging two apps from different accounts

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have created both iOS app and android app with different firebase analytics account. Is there anyway i can able to merge it together without losing the already tracked datas

Comment: Take a look on this SO question, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688716/transferring-an-app-to-another-firebase-account