# Migrating projects is not an option in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, migration, google-iam

We have created an organization within GCP and we have a lot of old projects in Firebase we would like to migrate into our organization. In GCP, we see this long list of projects which is not currently under our organization. By selecting most of the projects, we got the option to migrate these into our organization. But we have a list of residual projects now which does not enable the Migrate button if we select them.

I've set my self as owner in Firebase Console for the projects and I have Organization, Project and Firebase admin rights in GCP.

If I use the cloud shell, I get this response:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.projects.move) User [my email] does not have permission to access project [project to move] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

Would be thankful if anybody can point us in the right direction here. What are the requirements for beeing able to move or migrate projects from Firebase into organizations in GCP? Documentation doesn't say much regarding this.

Comment: Have you tried these steps here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688716/transferring-an-app-to-another-firebase-account

Comment: Yes, I'm already the owner of the Firebase project and I have admin rights for our organization in GCP. The problem is that the projects are listed under "No organization" and can't be moved within our organization. We could move most of the projects, but we still have about 30 left and it's really time consuming to handle roles for all of thouse independently instead of doing this within the organization policy.

Comment: That is some power usage for projects. I would go as far as literally e-mailing the support to do that for you. Especially if you have quite some traffic and don't want to have a complete blackout of service.

Comment: I just remembered I had once an issue with IAM/admin rights, when there was ANOTHER "organization" above the project level, because we were using G Suite. I had to get rights as an admin to G Suite and then I had all the rights to transfer all assets/projects.