# Merging firebase iOS & Android apps from different projects into one Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase

I am looking for help merging Firebase projects.

**Current Setup:** There are two different projects (iOS & Android) on two different accounts.

**Firebase Project 1:** iOS App using account abc@gmail.com

**Firebase Project 2:** Android App using account xyz@gmail.com

**Goal:** Combine both apps into a single Firebase project. **Firebase Project:** iOS and Android App using Account abc@gmail.com

Please help me with this. Thanks

**Note:-** I am able to move one project from one account to another account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to merge projects. In this case, if you want to have both apps in one project, lets say "Firebase project 1", you will need to create an Android app in "Firebase project 1" with the same package name. Then update the app with the new google-services.json file. With this you will have both apps under the same project but note that historical data won't be available.

If you are using Authentication, you may need to export the Auth info, see this [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth).

Similarly, you can do this also for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).

Not all the Firebase products have an option for exporting/importing data, so keep that in mind.